# ssh: sending a tmux command containing RETURN

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I have a server running where I have a `tmux` session running.

If I'm logged into the server, I can run

```
tmux send-keys -t mysess "list^M"
```

Note the `^M`! I type this by doing CTRL-V and then Return in bash. This sends the return key to the tmux session.

Now, I can also do the same by sending the command over ssh:

```
ssh myfancyserver tmux send-keys -t mysess "list^M"
```

All good.

However, now I want to do the same thing in python. **No Luck!**

I tried

```
subprocess.check_output(
    'ssh myfancyserver tmux send-keys -t mysess "list\x10"')
```

Because [I read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#Control_characters) that 10 is line feed. No luck!

I tried entering the newline with CTRL-V and Return within the python source but this breaks the file.

I also tried some stuff with paramiko, including using `channel.send` and `exec_command` - both no luck.

---

My feeling is that the newline gets lost somewhere along the transmission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^M` (CR) is `\x0d`, not `\x10` (and `^J` aka LF is `\0x0a` so this is really neither). In Python, you can also represent it with `\r` which is probably more readable and less error-prone.

According to http://jkorpela.fi/chars/c0.html the meaning of `\x10` (DLE) is

> A transmission control character which will change the meaning of
>   a limited number of contiguously following characters.
>   Its *[sic]* is used exclusively to provide
>   supplementary data transmission control functions.
>   Only graphic characters and transmission control characters
>   can be used in DLE sequences.

LF is 10 in decimal; maybe you are getting mixed up about the base. `\x` means the following two digits are hexadecimal. (Still then CR would be 13, not 10.)

Comment: *facepalm* I did not think this through, you are right. I can just put `"list\r"`. Thanks a lot!! On that note, I do have to say that I always find it confusing to match between integer represenation / short codes / `^` codes and python/C codes.

Comment: An ASCII chart on your cubicle wall might help. On many modern platforms, `man ascii` gets you a listing.